# Qt 5.4 beta WebEngineView Debugging

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, chromium, qtwebengine

I'm currently working on a VS2013 project which uses Qt 5.4. beta.
I use a QWebEngineView (which is part of the Chromium based QWebEngine), which loads Javascript/HTML pages from a webserver.

I would like to know if there are any possibilities debugging javascript and HTML for that QWebEngineView (or more generally QWebEngine).

I saw some notions of "devtools" in the webengine source code, maybe that could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicate my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28444368/1113207) for same question:

You can do it with older QWebView, see [QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsettings.html).

Docs have nothing about same for QWebEngineView, but I found this [link](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebengine/source) (look at line 47). I didn't try if it works, but you can try. May be dev tools will be available in one of the following QT versions.